# Cannot access a child window's controls ( Created with CDialog::Create )

Tags: visual-c++, parent-child, cdialog

I've been having some difficulties to understand and maybe you guys can help.

I have a project that uses CDialog and I've been trying to create a child window that retrieves some info from the main window ( the main/child windows have they're own classes), edits the content and sends the edited info back to the main window.

When I tried using `CDialog::Create()`, I wasn't able to use ANY of the controls on the child window. ( Example: Buttons are not responsive )

When I created the child window with `DoModal()` it backfired.. Buttons were responsive, and I had access to the child window's class functions, but when I tried to get the info from the main window class I was struck down with an appcrash.
I have tried passing the CWnd manually but it still crashed.. (Could not retrieve the main window handle )

Any ideas on how can I create the child window while still having access to the main app's variables and to the child window's event handlers ?

EDIT:
Ok, I finally found out what was the problem:
I was using

```
CDialog *eTest = new CDialog; // Pointing to .. ?? .. yeah I hate myself for this
eTest->Create(IDD_EDIT_DIALOG, NULL);
eTest->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Instead, I should of created the window like this:

```
CDialog *eTest = new CEditDialog(); //  Pointing to the dialog class
eTest->Create(IDD_EDIT_DIALOG, this);
eTest->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Everything from the buttons to the data transfer seems to be working right now.
  I hope it can help someone as dumb as me in the future.

Comment: You only fixed half of the mistake. The type for eTest should be CEditDialog*.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I found that out myself later that day but forgot to edit it here also, if it remained 'CDialog' I still wouldn't have been able to use the functions inside the main class.